# Conditional .length of a list

Tags: javascript

I have a list with the following values:

```
const myList = [True, False, False]
```

With **myList.length** I get the value **3**.

Now I want the length of the list with all **False** values.

How can I return the length with a condition?

Comment: You can `filter` it first then invoke `length`

Comment: please add the values of `True` and `False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const myList = [True, False, False].filter(el => el === false)
console.log(myList.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter()` to do it

```
let len = myList.filter(i => !i).length
```

```js
const myList1 = [true, false, false]
let len1 = myList1.filter(i => !i).length
console.log(len1)

const myList2 = ['True', 'False', 'False']
let len2 = myList2.map(i => i.toLowerCase() === 'true').filter(i => !i).length
console.log(len2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could count the values.

```js
const
    True = true,
    False = false,
    getCount = (array, value) => array.reduce((t, v) => t + (v === value), 0),
    myList = [True, False, False];

console.log(getCount(myList, False));
```